# How to add a parameter to a URL in GWT?

Tags: java, url, gwt, anchor

I have a Java/GWT application. In that there is a list of items. If I click on any item title then that item is opened with full description.

I am using Anchor for the item title, so what I want is when user clicks on item title then in the URL the id of that item is appended to the current URL.

For example, this is my URL:

`"http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#listItem?list"`

and I have to append id to the end of the URL like:

```
"http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#listItem?list&itemId=55"
```

Comment: You should probably use `com.google.gwt.user.client.History`, and replace your `Anchor` with an `Hyperlink`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Window.Location should do your trick : [see the doc here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html)

Something like  this :

```
String url = Window.Location.getHref();
url = url + "&itemId=" + itemId;
Window.Location.replace(url);
```

Although of course, as Crollster pointed out, you should insert your url parameter before the # sign. Give more details on what you're looking for exactly (why do you have to add the parameter manually, does the page have to reload ...)

Comment: I think this will reload the page...and I does not want to refresh the page....
I want this becoz I want to know which Item I am viewing....and for further needs I will collect the Id from url...

Answer (score 1):

you can use redirect command in order to add this parameter

```
response.sendRedirect(your url + itemId=55);
```

Then you can extract this variable.

I hope this will help.

Comment: I want to do this at client side...there is no server call or no url refreshed... :(

Comment: @milind_ensarm so you can use [java script redirect](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `javascript` coding.When the user clicks on link, get this `URL` and appends your id to it and reconstruct the `URL`.

Answer (score 0):

You see that `#` in the URL? Thats an anchor - you will need your parameter to be added **before** that, so it looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&itemId=55#listItem?list
```

HTH

Answer (score -2):

[URIBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) of Apache HttpComponents offers a convenient method to add parameters and will deal with existing query parameters and anchors.